# Time Remapping Panel Greyed Out for Colour Channel Mixer

Tags: kdenlive, visual-effects

A lot of effects in KDE support automation/animation. However, effects such as the colour channel mixer don't seem to have this option. Here's a screenshot of the greyed out time remapping panel (top mid-left):

[image: Time Remapping Panel Greyed Out]

My goal is to be able to automate some sort of colour rotation, which doesn't seem to be possible with this effect for some reason. Why is my time remapping panel greyed out for that effect amongst others, and is my assumption accurate that animation for that effect is unavailable?